# Can Excel identify the cells that form a perimeter around cells of a certain value?

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2013 to create a simple tool whose main input is individual depth measurements organized in a grid-like fashion (8 cells x 8 cells).  I want the user to be able to input the actual depth data, but during the subsequent calculations that involve finding the average depth in the 8x8 grid, I would like the tool to ignore the values adjacent to the instances of the maximum values, and instead perform calculations as if they all had that maximum value.

It doesn't need to be exact, per se, and it doesn't need to be accomplished this way either.  I also tinkered with just identifying how many columns and how many rows in the grid contained a max value, and figuring out some factor to multiply or add to those, but couldn't really get that working either.

I did figure out how to count my number of instances of max values, i.e.:

```
COUNTIF(range,MAX(range))
```

The problem with that approach seems to be that there is a huge difference between the number of cells adjacent to these max values when the max values are one solid block, and when the max values are arranged like a donut, in which case there is an interior perimeter as well.

Does anyone have any thoughts?  Anyone try something like this before?  I can share any other details you guys require.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to visualise your problem. An image of your data would be helpful

Comment: Are the maximum values you are referring to the absolute deepest points of the entire 8x8 grid (and you may have a a few repeats of that maximum value) or just locally the deepest points?

Comment: Create a helper array of the same size that substitutes the maximum value in a cell if that cell adjacent to the maximum, then take the average of that.  This could be done with an IF statement of the form `=IF(OR(cell_up = array_max, cell_right = array_max, cell_left = array_max, cell_down = array_max), array_max, cell_value)`.  It will be far easier to see what it is doing with this method and significantly easier that trying to build an `=AVERAGE( ...)` formula. (I doubt that is practical anyway)